# Kubernetes: link a pod to kube-proxy

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

As I understand it, kube-proxy runs on every Kubernetes node (it is started on Master and on the Worker nodes)

If I understand correctly, it is also the 'recommended' way to access the API (see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.md#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)

So, since kube-proxy is already running on every node, is the 'recommended' way to start each pod with a new kube-proxy container in it, or is it possible to 'link' somehow to the running kube-proxy container?

Originally I was using the URL with $KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and the credentials passed as a Secret, on GKE, 
calling

```
curl https://$USER:$PASSWORD@${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}/api/v1/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/endpoints/${SELECTOR}
```

and parsing the results, but on K8s deployed on a CoreOS cluster I only seem to be able to authenticate through TLS and certs and the linked proxy seems like a better way.

So, I'm looking for the most efficient / easiest way to connect to the API from a pod to look up the IP of another pod referred to by a Service.

Any suggestion/input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple options here, as noted in the doc link you provided.

The preferred method is using [Service Accounts](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/service-accounts.md) to access the API:

The short description is that your service would read the service-account secrets (token / CA-cert) that are mounted into the pod, then inject the token into the http header and validate the apiserver cert using the CA-cert. This somewhat simplifies the description of service accounts, but the above link can provide more detail.

Example using curl and service-account data inside pod:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces
```

Another option, mentioned in the link you provided, is to run a side-car container running a "kubectl proxy" in the same pod as your application.

A note of clarification: the "kube-proxy" and "kubectl proxy" are not referring to the same thing. The kube-proxy is responsible for routing "service" requests, kubectl proxy is a cli cmd which opens a local proxy to the Kubernetes API.

What is happening under the covers when running `kubectl proxy` is that the kubectl command already knows how to use the service-account data, so it will extract the token/CA-cert and establish a connection to the API server for you, then expose an interface locally in the pod (which you can use without any auth/TLS).

This is might be an easier approach as it likely requires no changes to your existing application, short of pointing it to the local kubectl proxy container running in the same pod.

One other side-note: I'm not sure of your exact use-case, but generally it would be preferable to use the Service IP / Service DNS name and allow Kubernetes to handle service discovery, rather than extracting the pod IP itself (the pod IP will change if the pod gets scheduled to a different machine).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, 
I was still confused about how to use the kubectl proxy: it's available on localhost, but to me kubectl is a command line tool, how do I use the side car container?
This 'example' https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.0/examples/kubectl-container explains a bit and I hope I get it right:kubectl with the ' -p proxy 8001' argument basically acts as a pass through 
The connected pod uses wget to localhost and the 8001 port and that means kubectl actually receives HTTP requests and forwards those to the api server. Is that correct?

Comment: btw: I know I can use service names and take advantage of DNS, but some  services like HBase seem to refer to nodes by hostname. There is a whole issue thread about DNS for pods and it's just been pushed, but meanwhile I need an alternative.

Comment: @MrE that's pretty much what is going on. All of the containers in a pod will basically share the same network. So in one container, you're running a proxy via long-lived cli command (`kubectl proxy`), and in your application container you are connecting to that proxy over localhost.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928755/gke-secured-access-to-services-from-outside-the-cluster  and I still can't get that to work. SInce it is related, maybe you can help:
Does the proxy also allow me to talk to the service (i.e. to connect to the service itself, on it's port, not just get it's metadata from the api-server?)
For example I would like to connect to a db defined as mongodb:27017 as a Service but not exposed to the outside. Can I use the kubectl proxy as a pass-through somehow?