# GKE: secured access to services from outside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any way to access the 'internal' services (those not exposed outside) of the cluster in a secure way from the outside.

The goal is simple: I need to debug clients of those services and need to access them, but don't want to expose them outside.

On a regular single host I would normally tunnel to the host with SSH and map the ports to localhost; I tried using a SSHD container but that didn't get me very far: the services are not directly on that container so I'm not sure how to get to the next hop on the network since the services are dynamically managing IPs.

Ideally a VPN would be much more convenient, but GKE doesn't seem to support VPN for road warrior situation.

Is there any solution for this use-case?

Thanks for your input.

EDIT:

I see here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.md#ways-to-connect

that the only way to connect supported right now is HTTP/HTTPS meaning I can proxy HTTP calls but not to any port

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a combination of running `kubectl proxy` on your dev machine and using the proxying functionality built into the master (that's a lot of proxying, but bear with me).

First, run `kubectl proxy`. Note the port that is bound locally (it should be 8001 by default). This will cause kubectl to create a tunnel to your master instance that you can hit locally without needing to pass any authentication (technically, you can do all of the following steps without doing this first by hitting the master directly, but this is simpler for debugging).

Next, point a client (web browser, curl, etc) at `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/<ns>/services/<svc>/`, replacing `<ns>` with the namespace in which your service is configured and `<svc>` with the name of your service. You can also append a particular request path to the end of the URL, so if your pods behind the service are hosting a file called `data.json` you would append that to the end of the request path.

This is how the [update-demo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/user-guide/update-demo) tutorial works, so if you get stuck I'd recommend walking through that example and taking a close look at what the [javascript](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/update-demo/local/script.js) does (it isn't too complicated).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try but I am not sure how I would specify the port of my service here: let's say I want to connect to my zookeeper cluster, inside the k8s cluster I reach it at zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 but externally with the proxy, how does the port play out? Is it understood by the proxy to direct to the right port?

Comment: You said you wanted to connect to an internal service, so I was explaining how to connect to a Kubernetes service (http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html). If you want to connect to a specific pod or node, you can do that using the proxy on the master as well -- instead of /services use /pods or /nodes.

Comment: Zk1,zk2, zk3 are services. The question is about the port, but I will try tomorrow and get back if I have more questiosn. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this and here is what i get:
`curl -v http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/zk1-dev` gives me a 500 error:
`{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for \"zk1-dev\"",
  "code": 500
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}`
What could be wrong here? 
Plus this gives me the info on the service, but i don't see how this allows me to connect to it. Please enlight me... I'm confused: I looked at the example you recommended and it seems to do work with the meta-data only.

Comment: i do have a service and endpoints attached as seen in:
`$ k describe service zk1-dev                                                                                                                    ✹Name:   zk1-dev
Namespace:  default
Labels:   id=1,name=zookeeper,track=dev,v=0
Selector:  id=1,name=zookeeper,track=dev
Type:   ClusterIP
IP:   None
Port:   zk-client 2181/TCP
Endpoints:  10.2.76.13:2181
Port:   zk-host 2888/TCP
Endpoints:  10.2.76.13:2888
Port:   zk-peers 3888/TCP
Endpoints:  10.2.76.13:3888
Session Affinity: None
No events.`

Comment: It sounds like you have a 'nominal' service and the service proxy may not work with those yet.

Comment: not sure to understand what that means. What's a nominal service and what else should/could it be to make this work?

Comment: If the port is named on the service, say `zk1:portname`.  if it is not named, just say `zk1`.  It looks like your port is named `zk-client` or `zk-host` or `zk-peers`

Answer (score 2):

After trying the many methods explained in the doc mentioned above, the thing that works for me was:

1) Create a SSHD daemon container to SSH to the cluster
2) Create a ssh Service with a `type: NodePort`

3) get the port number with 
`kubectl describe service sshd`

4) use ssh port forwarding to get to the service with:

`ssh -L <local-port>:<my-k8s-service-name>:<my-k8s-service-port> -p <sshd-port> user@sshd-container`

for example

`ssh -L 2181:zookeeper:2181 -p 12345 root@sshd-container`

Then I have my zookeeper service on localhost:2181
For more port mappings, use alternate ports.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using `kubectl port-forward`:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-to-applications-port-forward/

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_port-forward/

Example:

`kubectl port-forward POD_NAME LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_PORT`

`kubectl port-forward redis-master 6379:6379`

Comment: i resolved all this by adding a vpn server pod to my cluster, and it is as if i was inside the cluster. port forward is basically exposing the local node to the outside which i do not want to do.